# change prestashop slider animation

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I need to change the default image slider animation from slide to fade in prestashop 1.7
I tried to add `mode: fade,` to homeslider.js, but it did not help.
here is the homeslider.js file:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var homesliderConfig = {
    speed: 500,            // Integer: Speed of the transition, in milliseconds
    timeout: $('.homeslider-container').data('interval'), // Integer: Time between slide transitions, in milliseconds
    nav: true,             // Boolean: Show navigation, true or false
    random: false,          // Boolean: Randomize the order of the slides, true or false
    pause: $('.homeslider-container').data('pause'), // Boolean: Pause on hover, true or false
    maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
    namespace: "homeslider",   // String: Change the default namespace used
    before: function(){},   // Function: Before callback
    after: function(){}     // Function: After callback
  };

  $(".rslides").responsiveSlides(homesliderConfig);

});
```

The mode fade thing I saw in a prestashop 1.6 topic, but it does not work in prestashop 1.7
Can somebody help me?

Comment: here you can find the official documentation of responsiveSlider.js http://responsiveslides.com/

Comment: Thanks for that, but in the documentation the animation is already set to fade, and in prestashop it is set to "slide". Do you mean it is a CSS issue instead of a js one?

Comment: it could be so. inspecting the code from example page i see that slider is initializated with just few option {speed: 1000, maxwidth: 800}  so i think is PS override of origina responsiveSlider. try to change the value of namespace:"homeslider" to namespace: "rslides". is just an attempt but may it cuold be works

Comment: That did not change it either. In fact nothing changed. But I did find something in the CSS, that changed removed the animation completely: 
`.carousel-inner>.carousel-item {
        transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform .6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
        perspective: 1000px
    } `

Comment: yes, manually (deleting everything in var/cache) and from BO

Comment: inspecting the code of slide, while it's sliding, can you see any changes in class attribute or in his HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200170/discussion-between-todor-inchovski-and-sim1-81).

Comment: i posted an answer to help the others with the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a CSS behavior, to change it you have to edit your slider styles

find .carousel-inner>.carousel-item into your CSS files and change in

```
.carousel-inner>.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;

}
```

next find .carousel-inner>.carousel-item.active and add opacity: 1

```
.carousel-inner>.carousel-item.active{
    transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

then you can comment the follow css

```
/*.carousel-inner>.active.left {*/
/*left: -100%*/
/*}*/

/*.carousel-inner>.active.right {*/
/*left: 100%*/
/*}*/
```

you also need to be comment out:

```
@media (-webkit-transform-3d),(transform-3d)
```

now your slide is in fade mode you have only to play with `transition: all .6s linear;` to adjust the timing of new animation

Comment: can you come to chat again to discuss this, because there are still some issues, and your answer is almost complete and I want to accept it.